How to install Ubuntu on laptop with a busted display
I have a reasonably high end mechrevo/mechrev0 laptop (Core i9, 64GB RAM, decent GPU) with a busted display (the panel literally falls out of its case). I've tried to get the display repaired several times, but it keeps falling out, perhaps through poor workmanship or poor design or just a defect. I don't know which and I can't fix it right now for a bunch of reasons not germane to this question. The display is basically inoperable in its current state.
Aside from that, the laptop appears to be in working order and has Windows 11 installed and running fine. I can access the laptop through built-in and/or USB keyboard/mouse and an attached HDMI secondary display.
I'd like to install Ubuntu desktop or server on the laptop, but the installer (on a USB stick) doesn't auto-detect the HDMI display or just doesn't display there by default. I've tried this with different external HDMI displays, to no avail. I don't know the exact settings of the BIOS, but I believe it may be set to boot from USB drive first. When I press F2 repeatedly on restart with the USB installer plugged in, Windows doesn't come up (though of course the laptop display stays dark), so I assume it's sitting in a prompt that I can't see.
Is there a way I could get an installation going on this machine, preferably in a way that won't destroy the existing Windows 11 partition?  I already have wsl on this machine, but I need to do certain things with virtualization that are impractical under wsl, so the question is really about getting Ubuntu installed directly on the boot drive.
I'm hoping for some magical key combination that will auto-switch the display or some other trick of that type, but any answer that gets me there would be amazing.
The laptop has USB a & c ports, HDMI, and Ethernet, but nothing else.  I'm handy with a command-line and even gcc, but I don't hand roll my own device drivers or even build my own kernels. I can sometimes handle a screwdriver without anyone getting hurt.
After opening up the case, I see that it's unlikely I'll be able to make any modifications myself.  So, I'm looking for a pure software solution, if one exists.

If you can open up the system, try disconnecting the internal display. About 10 years ago I was in a similar situation and disconnecting the LVDS cable from the internal display was enough for both UEFI and Ubuntu to start showing up on the external HDMI monitor.

thanks @muru I'll go find my screwdriver I guess... :)

Seems what you have is strictly a hardware question.

@david - I would call this an installer question that may have a hardware solution.

I've installed various Ubuntu product/releases on a laptop that had a unreadable display.. and the easiest way was using the machine's own option to change the display being used (ie, toggle of both internal+external/internal.only/external.only/mirror/etc) but what features your machine has here is device (firmware) specific. The key that does this is device specific (varying on make/model as machine firmware is involved I believe; the toggle having different options (3-5) varying on device)

thanks @guiverc - any hints about how I might go searching for this type of functionality?  like, how did you find the supported affordances on the platforms that you worked on?

@muru - I updated the question with a few words based on your suggestion.  After opening the case, it wasn't at all obvious to me what the right cable to detach was or whether the relevant cable is accessible.  I don't see an obvious way into the hinge portion of the case and I really would like to avoid damaging the hardware by poking around naively, which is the only way I could do it...

It was a key on the keyboard that with Fn (or Fn+Ctrl) that key toggle between what displays where using... It exists on ancient IBM, more modern Lenovo, Dells, I don't see it on a nearby HP.. but the function can sometimes be there even if there is nothing on key (see what combination worked on older models & try that is how I'd look).. but it's picture on keys related to screen(s); with that  graphic varying on make/model mostly but also over time.

@guiverc - got it thanks ; I'll try to poke around but the obvious combinations have not yielded anything yet.  There are keys on the keyboard that look like they may be display-related (F3).  So I guess this means that your previous research hasn't turned up any way to cause the installer to target alternative displays.

You can install a portable Ubuntu Server on a USB-connected SSD in another computer and then move it to the computer with a failing screen and boot into it. Then you should be able to access Ubuntu Server via SSH from another computer and that might be good enough for your 'things with virtualization'. See the following links: Ubuntu Server from compressed image and simple graphics in Ubuntu Server.

@sudodus - thanks!  I was not aware of the pre-installed server images.  Yes, if I could boot into server off pre-installed usb-stick and then just ssh in that would be fine for my purpose; great even since I wouldn't disturb the windows install and I could probably re-partition the disk from server.  I guess then the question is whether the BIOS is setup to boot from usb-stick first; I'll test that.  If it's not, it's making me wonder whether I might be able to use windows recovery to try to boot the usb stick in some way...

If you are lucky, the computer can already boot from USB. Otherwise, an alternative might be to unplug the internal drive (which probably is an nvme stick). Then the computer should boot from USB. (An obvious drawback is that it is not convenient to unplug and replug the internal drive to switch between Windows and Ubuntu.) Let us hope that you will find a way to 'see' the menus of the UEFI-BIOS system, and get it set correctly to boot from USB, when there is a bootable system in the USB drive, and otherwise boot into Windows).

Another alternative, that might work is to create a virtual system using VirtualBox and install Ubuntu (Server or Desktop) in the virtual system. Running Ubuntu like that is 'more similar' to running Ubuntu on bare metal compared to using WSL. But maybe your 'things with virtualization' would not work that way.

thanks for the thoughts @sudodus - I'm still fiddling with the pre-installed server usb stick.  unplugging the internal drive seems doable as it was reasonably accessible when I opened the case.  doing everything under windows probably won't work out as I need to nest VMs a bit.

fwiw, it appears the installer has some sort of built-in ssh support: https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/tutorial/operate-server-installer.html

well, I removed the internal drives, plugged in the external usb, and restarted but unfortunately I don't see the system come up on my local network.  fwiw, I was able to boot from that same usb stick using qemu on another box and ssh into the resulting vm, so the idea should work in principle.  Perhaps the BIOS is set to not boot from from USB in some way.  I also tried to restart windows into WinRT but that seems to use only the main display, not the HDMI.  As a last ditch effort, I could try to install those internal drives on another machine with a working display and install there...

Closing this out with my own answer, which is what I ultimately did to resolve the problem, helped along by all the comments I received.
Adapting @sudodus' suggestions, I installed ubuntu server on a separate M.2 drive on another computer, removed the drives in the laptop, and just started up the laptop with the newly installed drive instead.  Ubuntu server started up with ssh pre-installed and I was able to ssh in to use the hardware.  This seems like the most general approach, though it is not really the kind of software solution I was hoping for.  It also doesn't resolve how to change the UEFI-BIOS settings without repairing the display.  Presumably due to UEFI-BIOS settings, booting off of a pre-installed server USB stick did not work on my laptop, which is why the M.2 change was required.
The comments by @guiverc were closest to what I was hoping for, but I was unable to find out whether there are keystrokes to re-point mechrevo/mechrev0 to HDMI display.
